# Misalignment using JQuery Datatable with Scroller, FixedColumns plugins

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

**My issue:**

I have an issue of misalignment in my table I couldn't solve it, I need to make the parts circled in red in the image to be aligned with the fixed columns (the 3 first columns).

I was analysing the `html` with `Firebug` and playing with the `html attributes` I almost fixed it, it is in the tag: `DTFC_LeftWrapper`. I will be still be trying to find the problem.

I am using `JQuery Datatable` with `Scroller` and `FixedColumn` plugin:

**Bootstrap v3.3.5, DataTables 1.10.9, Scroller 1.2.2, FixedColumns 3.1.0**

```
Scroller/css/dataTables.scroller.min.css
bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.css
FixedColumns-3.1.0/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.css

Scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js
bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js
FixedColumns-3.1.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.js
```

**Results:**

[image]

**And this javascript:**

```
table.DataTable({ "dom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>", // datatable layout without  horizontal scroll
                stateSave: true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bSort": sorting,
                "bInfo": false,
                "scrollY": scrollsize,
                "scrollX": "true",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "paging": false              
            });

new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table, { leftColumns: 3 });
```

**Html:**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" id="datatableList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @*<th>Picking Team</th>*@
            <th class="width-300">Master Account Name</th>
            <th>Cut-Off</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            @* CREATES THE COLUMNS *@
            @for (var line = 0; line < Model.MaxColumns; line++)
            {
                <th class="text-center">Time</th>
                <th>Batch</th>
                <th class="text-center">Orders</th>
                <th class="right-border-2">Actions</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @* CREATES LINES FOR EACH MASTER ACCOUNT *@
        @foreach (var masterAccount in Model.AllMasterAccounts.OrderBy(x => x.TeamPickingId).ThenBy(y => y.MasterAccountName))
        {
            <tr masteraccountid="@masterAccount.Id">
                @*<td class="bg-grey-cararra">@(masterAccount.TeamPicking == null ? string.Empty : @masterAccount.TeamPicking.Name)</td>*@
                <td class="bg-grey-cararra">@masterAccount.MasterAccountName</td>
                <td class="bg-grey-cararra">@GeneralHelper.ConvertTo12HrsFormat(masterAccount.DailyOrderCutOffTime)</td>
                <td class="bg-grey-cararra"><a class="label label-sm bg-green">Completed</a></td>
                @{
            var batchPickingList = Model.AllBatchPickingSummaries.Where(x => x.MasterAccountId == masterAccount.Id).OrderBy(y => y.BatchDateTime);
            var missingColumns = Model.MaxColumns - batchPickingList.Count();
                }
                @foreach (var batchPicking in batchPickingList)
                {
                    var statusColour = string.Empty;//batchPicking.StatusColour();

                    <td class="@statusColour">@batchPicking.BatchDateTime.ToString(GeneralHelper.TimeFormat24H)</td>
                    <td class="@statusColour">@batchPicking.BatchNumber</td>
                    <td class="@statusColour text-center">@batchPicking.TotalOrders</td>
                    <td class="right-border-2"><a action="SetPrinted">Set Printed</a></td>
                }

                @* CREATES THE MISSING COLUMNS *@
                @for (var line = 0; line < missingColumns; line++)
                {
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="right-border-2"><a action="setNoOrders">No Orders</a></td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce that behaviour in a fiddle? I cannot, seems not to be related to FixedColumns.

Comment: Not sure if this applies to you, but v1.10.10 has been released and in the release notes under "fixes", column alignment is specifically mentioned. [release notes](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/).